# find(1): how is the star wildcard implemented for it to fail on some filenames?

Tags: shell, find, filenames, wildcards, character-encoding

In a file system where filenames are in UTF-8, I have a file with a faulty name; it is displayed as: `D�sinstaller`, actual name according to zsh:  `D$'\351'sinstaller`, Latin1 for `Désinstaller`, itself a French barbarism for "uninstall."  Zsh would not match it with `[[ $file =~ '^.*$' ]]` but would match it with a globbing `*`—this is the behavior I expect.

Now I still expect to find it when running `find . -name '*'`—as a matter of fact, I would never expect a filename to fail this test.  However, with `LANG=en_US.utf8`, the file does *not* show up, and I have to set `LANG=C` (or `en_US`, or `''`) for it to work.

**Question:**  What is the implementation behind, and how could I have predicted that outcome?

<sub>Infos: Arch Linux 3.14.37-1-lts, find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2</sub>

Comment: have you considered `convmv` to convert file names to utf-8?

Comment: @richard: In fact, I use to rely on `[[ $file =~ '^.*$' ]]` failing to use `recode` on the file name, but I'll now look into `convmv` if need be.  Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's a really nice catch. From a quick look at the source code for GNU find, I would say this boils down to how `fnmatch` behaves on invalid byte sequences (`pred_name_common` in `pred.c`):

```
b = fnmatch (str, base, flags) == 0;
(...)
return b;
```

This code tests the return value of `fnmatch` for equality with 0, but does not check for errors; this results in any errors being reported as "doesn't match".

It has been suggested, many years ago, to change the behavior of this libc function to always return true on the `*` pattern, even on broken file names, but from what I can tell the idea must have been rejected (see the thread starting at https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-hacker/2002-11/msg00071.html):

> > When fnmatch detects an invalid multibyte character it should fall back to
> >     single byte matching, so that "*" has a chance to match such a string.
>
> And why is this better or more correct?  Is there existing practice?

As mentioned by Stéphane Chazelas in a comment, and also in the same 2002 thread, this is inconsistent with the glob expansion performed by shells, which do not choke on invalid characters. Perhaps even more puzzling is the fact that reversing the test will match only those files that have broken names (create files in bash with `touch $'D\351marrer' $'Touch\303\251' $'\346\227\245\346\234\254\350\252\236'`):

```
$ find -name '*'
.
./Touché
./日本語

$ find -not -name '*'
./D?marrer
```

So, to answer your question, you could have predicted this by knowing the behavior of your `fnmatch` in this case, and knowing how `find` handles this function's return value; you probably could not have found out solely by reading the documentation.

Comment: My guess for why there is no fix for `*` is that then it would be inconsistent with `D*staller`.

Comment: @richard, the idea would be that `D*staller` would match on `$'D\351sinstaller'` as well like it does in the glob of all the shells I've tested. Given that GNU fnmatch behaviour is not consistent with that of the GNU shell, I'd say it's a bug.

Comment: Great indepth answer, dhag; much appreciated.  Would you mind pointing out the standard spec to which fnmatch complies?  I can find the usual POSIX regexp spec specifying that `.` should only match valid characters in the encoding—hence my expectation that `.*` does not match invalid strings—but I cannot find a matching specification for the globbing star.

Comment: The closest specification I can find online is on [this OpenGroup page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13).  It states *Matching shall be based on the bit pattern used for encoding the character, not on the graphic representation of the character.* and *The <asterisk> is a pattern that shall match any string, including the null string.*  This can arguably be interpreted as @StéphaneChazelas's suggestion.  13 years later, it may be time to ping upstream again :-)

Comment: @Michaël, I couldn't find anything better either. Perhaps, as a point of comparison, GNU find on Mac OS behaves in a way consistent with the shell's globbing (i.e., `-name '*'` matches all files, broken names included), so presumably BSD's version of `fnmatch`, which doesn't claim POSIX.2 cnoformance, unlike the GNU version, has a different, and arguably saner, interpretation of what should be done on invalid characters.

Answer (score 13):

[find](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) `-name` option uses shell [pattern matching notation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13) to perform matching filename. `*` is a pattern [matching multiple characters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_02), shall match a string of zero or more characters.

`find` uses [fnmatch](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fnmatch.html) to check pattern matching, so you can use [ltrace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ltrace) to check the result:

```
$ touch $'\U1212'aa
$ touch D$'\351'sinstaller
$ LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 ltrace -e fnmatch find -name '*'          
find->fnmatch("foo", "foo", 0)                   = 0
find->fnmatch("Foo", "foo", 0)                   = 1
find->fnmatch("Foo", "foo", 16)                  = 0
find->fnmatch("*", ".", 0)                       = 0
.
find->fnmatch("*", "D\351sinstaller", 0)         = -1
find->fnmatch("*", "\341\210\222aa", 0)          = 0
./ሒaa
+++ exited (status 0) +++
```

With `D\351sinstaller`, `fnmatch` return `-1`, indicated that it failed to match. A valid character like `ሒaa` will be matched.

In your case, with `UTF-8` locale, `\351` is an invalid character, causing pattern matching fail.

Comment: At the very least, +1 for the use of `ltrace`.  I did know about `strace`, but `ltrace` is new to me.  Lovely!